# Flex item aligns with label instead of with an input box

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have something like this

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <label>ID</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width: 13rem;" />
    </div>
    <select class="form-control" style="width: 13rem;">
        <option value="0">Select...</option>
        <option value="1">Other 1</option>
        <option value="2">Other 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The `select` that I have is aligning with the `ID` label instead of the input. Is there any way I can align it with the input without having to put a label on top of the `select`?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: You can use margin-top on select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `align-items-end` to the flex container (first-example).

If you want them to properly line up you will need to make the select element `form-control-sm` as well (second example).

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex align-items-end">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <label>ID</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width: 13rem;" />
    </div>
    <select class="form-control" style="width: 13rem;">
        <option value="0">Select...</option>
        <option value="1">Other 1</option>
        <option value="2">Other 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="d-flex align-items-end">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <label>ID</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width: 13rem;" />
    </div>
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width: 13rem;">
        <option value="0">Select...</option>
        <option value="1">Other 1</option>
        <option value="2">Other 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code and I think this is a good solution:

```html
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <label>ID</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width: 13rem;" />
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <label style="color: transparent;">ID</label>
        <select class="form-control" style="width: 13rem;">
            <option value="0">Select...</option>
            <option value="1">Other 1</option>
            <option value="2">Other 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think you are using bootstrap so I don't know if bootstrap will interfere with my code but try it out anyway.

Comment: The OP **specifically** did NOT want to add the label you have added.

Comment: i think that it will be too complicated to do it without the hidden label. i will try and research a bit more and give you a better answer.